# Situations in which to express integration constant as its natural log

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

What is the complete reasoning behind constants of integration, specifically in the case of the natural log?

Given $\int\left(\frac{1}{250-x}\right)dx=\int(dt)$ (1), I obtain:

$\ln\left(\frac{1}{250-x}\right)=t+C$

My textbook gives the solution for this problem as:

$\ln\left(\frac{1}{250-x}\right)=t+\ln(C)$

However, for another basic problem, we do not end up taking the natural log of the constant of integration:

$\int\left(\frac{1}{x(1-x)}\right)dx=\int(dt)$ (2)

The text finds:

$\ln\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)=t+C$

Why is the constant of integration expressed as its natural log in the case of 1, but not in the case of 2?

Comment: Just for conveience!

Comment: @DiegoMath We arrive at two different answers for the constant of integrations, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends upon the context of the problem.
In your first example it appears that perhaps one intends to solve for $x$ but in the second example it appears than one does not intend to solve for $x$. In the first example one immediately obtains 
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{250-x}=Ce^t
\end{equation}
by having expressed the constant in the form $\ln C$. If one wished to solve the second example for $x$ it would be better to use $\ln C$ there as well.

Comment: Does the fact that we can arrive at two different solutions for the constant of integration imply that such difference in expression is non-trivial?

Comment: Without additional information, one cannot determine the value of the constant of integration. However, when one has sufficient information to determine its value, the form it is written in makes no difference.  Suppose one student obtains $x=Ce^{3t}$ and another obtains $x=e^Ce^{3t}$. The first student uses additional information to get $C=2$ lets say. The second student used the same information to get $C=\ln2$. But both are correct. One student gets $y=2e^{3t}$ and the other gets $x=e^{\ln2}e^{3t}=2e^{3t}$. So the form in which the constant of integration was written does not matter so much